# Show remaining content

Tags: jquery, html

I've hidden the second paragraph in this example and would like to click 'read more..' to view it. Attempted the slideToggle and .show but neither seem to be taking effect, any obvious mishaps in my code?

http://jsfiddle.net/

```
<div class="cat-description">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/cache/Features/NEW-SITE-FEATURE.390.jpg?1076241667" alt="" title="" /></a>
    <h1>test title</h1>
    <p>paragraphy 1</p>
        <div class="showcontent">
        <a class="showcontent" href="#" id="show">read more ...</a></div>
        <div id="showcontent" style="display: none;">
<p>paragraph 2</p>
</div>

</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $("#show").click(function() {
        $("#showcontent").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: so you want to animate it?

Comment: Where is your fiddle? Its just a jsfiddle website link

Comment: [**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/7A62E/) ..
No changes required just add a reference to jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As taken from the comments, the solution was as follows.

"add jquery reference source"